# Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '~./node_modules/emailjs/smtp/message.js in the emailjs Package

Tags: angular, typescript

I have installed emailjs Package. I am referring to the  http://tphangout.com/angular-2-sending-mails-from-your-app/ Link to create a simple Angular app to send an email.

I am getting errors as per the attached image below[image]

I have installed emailJS package. Seeking for the help.

Comment: Do you use WebPack? If so, please ensure that you defined ".js" in "resolve.extensions".

Comment: I don't use webPack.

Comment: What's your angular version?

Comment: I am using angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Add these line to your package.json after devDependencies

"browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "net": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false,
    "os": false,
    "fs": false
  }